# Prove A Combinatorics Equality (Help!)

Tags: combinatorics

Yesterday I asked following question. It seems that my question is put on hold.

==========================================================

Prove following equality.

$$\left( \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{i} \left[ \sum\limits_{j=0}^{i-1} \binom{n}{j}  \right] \right) = 2^{2n},\quad\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^+\;\tag{1}.$$

Please help!

Thank you

==========================================================

**Answer:**

***Intuitively***

I just figured out that to prove Eq. (1) it is easier if I consider following case. Let Alex have $n+1$ fair coins and Bob have $n$ fair coins, where $n$ is a positive integer. Let $A$ be the event when Alex has more heads than Bob. Eq. (1) is the cardinality of event $A$.

The cardinality of event $A^C$ is 
$$\left( \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{i} \left[ \sum\limits_{j=i}^{n} \binom{n}{j}  \right] \right) \tag{2}.$$

Then, we can rephrase Eq. (2) into

$$|A^C| = \left( \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{n+1-i} \left[ \sum\limits_{j=i}^{n} \binom{n}{n-j}  \right] \right) \tag{3}.$$

By defining $k = n+1-i$ and $l=n-j$, we can get that $|A| = |A^C|$.

The union of event $A$ and $A^C$ forms the sample space $\Omega$. The cardinality of $|\Omega| = 2^{n+1}2^{n} = 2^{2n+1}$. At last, since the facts that $|A| = |A^C|$ and $|\Omega| = 2^{2n+1}$, we can get $|A| = 2^{2n}$ as shown in Eq. (1).

***Algebraically***

For me it is easier if I first change Eq. (1) into 
$$f(n) = \left( \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i} \left[ \sum\limits_{j=i+1}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{j}  \right] \right) = 2^{2n},\quad\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^+\;\tag{4}.$$

Then, algebraically

$$f(n) =
\begin{cases}
\overbrace{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{(n-1)/2} \binom{n}{k}}^{= 2^{n-1}} \overbrace{\sum\limits_{l=0}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{l}}^{= 2^{n+1}},  & \text{if $n$ is odd} \\
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}-1} \binom{n}{k} \underbrace{\sum\limits_{l=0}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{l}}_{= 2^{n+1}} + \binom{n}{n/2} \underbrace{\sum\limits_{l=\frac{n}{2}+1}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{l}}_{= 2^{n+1}/2 = 2^n}, & \text{if $n$ is even.}
\end{cases}$$

Next problem is how to prove $f(n) = 2^{2n}$ when $n$ is even. By factoring the $2^n$, we can get

$$f(n) = 2^n \underbrace{\left( 2 \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}-1} \binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{n/2} \right)}_{= 2^n}, \text{when $n$ is even}.$$ $$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Comment: Please show your efforts and clarify how $\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}\binom{n}{j}$ is defined when $i=0$.

Comment: That term equals 0. I have no idea. Any hints are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint 1: $$\binom{n+1}{i}=\binom{n}{i}+\binom{n}{i-1}\tag{1}$$
Hint 2: $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}=2^n,\qquad \sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}^2=\binom{2n}{n}\tag{2}$$
Hint 3: $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}f(i)\sum_{j<i}f(j)=\frac{1}{2}\,\left[\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n}f(i)\right)^2-\sum_{i=0}^{n}f(i)^2\right].\tag{3}$$